# From Odoo8 to Odoo11: rmanage report_sxw

Tags: module, odoo-8, odoo-11

I update my Odoo8 to an Odoo11. Then I try to reinstall a custom module named **probespoke** ( https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tcmjwWvigBeVd6yWUHO3-2u0Ane24xvz/view?usp=sharing ) that I sent to you to reproduce the issue. This module use an old module named **report** which was use until Odoo10.
You can see in probespoke.py that it is import line 2

`from openerp.report import report_sxw`

and then use line 292

`class pb_orders_products_report_parser(report_sxw.rml_parse):`

I don't find much information about how to get around this issue.
Maybe there is a solution here (https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/24798) but as I am still a beginner in Odoo developpement, I don't really understand what they are doing.

Does someone has an idea?

Thank you very much.